# How to obtain a list of all distinct first letters of given field

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, sqlite

Let's say I have this *Person* class that consist of *last_name* string field.

I would like to display links of **all first letters of names** existing in db.

So for example:
`A B D E...` when there's Adams, Brown, Douglas, Evans and no one that *last_name* starts with C.

Of course view is not a problem here as I want to prepare all of this on backend. So the question is how to write good model's or view's function that will provide this.

I would like it to be DB-independent, however tricks for any particular DB would be a bonus.

Also, I would like this to be quite well optimized in terms of speed because it could be a lot of names. It should be less naive than this most simple algorithm:

1. Get all people
2. Create set (because of the uniqueness of elements) of the first letters
3. Sort and return

So for example (in views.py):

```py
    names = Person.objects.values_list('last_name', flat=True)
    letters = {name[0] for name in names}
    letters_sorted = sorted(letters)
```

Of course I could *order_by* first or assign new attribute to each objects (containing first letter) but I don't think it will speed up the process.

I also think that assuming that **all letters are in use** is bad assumption if I would go check each letter if at least one name for this letter exists ;-)

Which approach would be best effective for databases and django here?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the orm methods to generate the list of initals (including count):

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import Left

initials = (Person
            .objects
            .annotate(initial=Left('last_name', 1))
            .values('initial')
            .annotate(count=Count('initial'))
            .order_by('initial'))
```

This will result in something like

```
<QuerySet [{'initial': 'A', 'count': 1},
           {'initial': 'B', 'count': 2},
           ...
           {'initial': 'Y', 'count': 1}]>
```

Comment: Looks like my favourite answer :-) The closest one to the DB, single db hit (or not?) and returns exactly the stuff I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would sort the names first, then unpack the names as arguments for `zip`, then consume just the first tuple that `zip` yields:

```
names = sorted(Person.objects.values_list('last_name', flat=True))

first_letters = next(zip(*names))
```

This doesn't use sets or remove duplicates or anything like that. Is that critical? If it is, you could do this:

```
names = Person.objects.values_list('last_name', flat=True)

first_letters = sorted(set(next(zip(*names))))
```

Though this would be hardly more performant that what you've already written.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
alphabet_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase) + list(string.ascii_uppercase)
result = dict(map(lambda x: (x, Person.objects.filter(name__start_with=x).exists()), alphabet_list))
```